# Add Secrets to gitlab-runner k8s pods

Tags: kubernetes, gitlab-ci-runner

I have a gitlab-runner deployed on my private k8s. It's runs ok but now I'd like to add the following feature.

I want a predefined secret be mounted to the executor pods. One example would be for example when I'm using kaniko I'd like that my docker config be mounted under /kaniko/.docker/.

Failed to find anyting online. Anyone know how to tackle this?

EDIT:

The runner itself is installed with helm, but that matters not. The yaml that is used for the pod in question is not in the templates, this pod is not created on `helm install` it's added later and lives only for the duration of the pipeline.

EDIT:

All the examples in the web writes to this file in `before script` section but I don't want to keep those creds on gitlab.

Comment: Just to clarify the question: You want to mount a secret into your pods under path: /kaniko/.docker/ ?

Comment: Correct, however I'm not the one deploying the pod. The pod is deployed after gitlab pipeline starts and I can't find out how to control it's configuration.